# Creating multiple records for a model as a table. Use nested resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want my User to create one **or various** Stock Shipments from the `StockShipment#new` view. The form should have one row as a table and user can add more rows in order to add new records.

Should I use a nested form for this and build them in my `create` method or should I use a normal StockShipment form and loop through the params passed and create a StockShipment for each?

I tried with nested resources but it's so confusing from the same model view.

I would appreciate help since I can't find nothing in the docs.

Thanks!